# S3 Signed URL is expired immediately

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've noticed an interesting behavior with S3 signed URLs that I can't explain.

I use the following code to generate an S3 signed URL:

```
s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: itemId,
        Expires: expirationTime
    })
```

When I create a signed URL with a Lambda function in `eu-central-1` it returns a valid URL that works fine and I can upload a file using it.

However, if I do this in the same Lambda function in `us-east-1` I get a URL that is expired immediately in the very same second a signed URL was generated. When I try to use a URL from `us-east-1` I get the following error:

[image]

I've also noticed that signed URLs from `us-east-1` (that does not work) and `eu-central-1` (that does work) contain different sets of parameters.

**us-east-1**

[image]

**eu-central-1**

[image]

Here are IAM permissions for the Lambda function in `us-east-1`:

[image]

Comment: You are probably missing the permission on your lambda IAM role for the particular region i.e. us-east-1.

Comment: @devutkarsh I've updated the question. IAM role does not seem to be the issue and it has (seemingly) correct permissions to access the S3 bucket.

Comment: Definitely not permissions-related.  Is this your *exact* code?  I've seen signed URLs expire immediately when `Expires` is a *string that looks like a number*, instead of an actual number.  It should be possible to force the SDK to use the V4 algorithm for all signatures, like your eu-central-1 example, which would also work around the issue and is probably a very good idea at this point, but I hate to bury/ignore bad behavior and would prefer to identify the cause of this problem before suggesting that approach.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Expriation time comes from another variable, I've updated the code to reflect this. I'll double-check the type and try to force the SDK V4 in both cases.

Comment: Maybe try `Expires: Number(expirationTime)` or `Expires: parseInt(expirationTime)`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Makes sense. Will try that and reply here later.